# Resharper Intellisense doesn't color class types, parameters, etc

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

When using Intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) it adds color to the class types, parameters, return type, etc. to the description, as demonstrated in this image:

[image]

Is it possible to get ReSharper (2016.1.2) to add color in a similar fashion to its description instead of only being black and white? Here's the example of ReSharper:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Enhanced Tooltip](https://github.com/MrJul/ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip/) ReSharper extension to bring colour back to your tooltips (C# files only though).

Actually this only changes the hover-over intelliSense. If you want the Visual Studio style statement completion then you can switch back by using `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`IntelliSense`->`General` and selecting 'Visual Studio' (or 'Custom IntelliSense' if you want to customize it a bit more)

ReSharper's IntelliSense may not have coloured tooltips but is more configurable and more intelligent than the Visual Studio version.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. Hopefully JetBrains will add it in the future.